# Reading file with "US-ASCII" encoding in Haskell: hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence)

Tags: file, haskell, encoding, io

I'm using Haskell for programming a parser, but this error is a wall I can't pass. Here is my code:

```
main = do
  arguments    <- getArgs
  let fileName = head arguments
  fileContents <- readFile fileName
  converter    <- open "UTF-8" Nothing
  let titleLength           = length fileName
      titleWithoutExtension = take (titleLength - 4) fileName
      allNonEmptyLines      = unlines $ tail $ filter (/= "") $ lines fileContents
```

When I try to read a file with "US-ASCII" encoding I get the famous error hGetContents: invalid argument (invalid byte sequence). I've tried to change the "UTF-8" in my code by "US-ASCII", but the error persist. Is there a way for reading this files, or any kind of file handling encoding problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should `hSetEncoding` to configure the file handle for a specific text encoding, e.g.:

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO

main = do
  (path : _) <- getArgs
  h <- openFile path ReadMode
  hSetEncoding h latin1
  contents <- hGetContents h
  -- no need to close h
  putStrLn $ show $ length contents
```

If your file contains non-ASCII characters and it's not UTF8 encoded, then latin1 is a good bet although it's not the only possibility.

Comment: Just curious: Why is there no need to close the handle? Just this week I used `withFile` since I thought that would save me from manually closing the handle.

Comment: Because `hGetContents` will close it once you have consumed all of the input.

Comment: @ErikR now my program works! thanks. Please can you tell me the other possibilities?

Comment: if your file really consists of just _bytes_, then perhaps you should read it as a ByteString. OTOH, if the file contains _text_ you should use the encoding that was used when the contents were written. See the [Unicode Encodings](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:24) section for a list of available encodings.